# Python 3 "Kernel" Module Not Found When Importing AIML

Tags: python, aiml

when I'm trying to import the AIML module I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiml\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Kernel import Kernel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Kernel'
```

Upon searching I can't find a "Kernel" module, how can I fix this error?